# laravel ORM how to access hasOne related table in view

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

I know this appears to be a simple question but after looking all through the official docs as well as 2 tutorials, it is not clear to me. There is conflicting examples of using foreign_keys or not as well as using the class Model:all() in different locations and for use with hasMany relationss... It seems a pretty simple thing to do so I am frustrated I cannot find the answer easily. I know the answer is probably there someone but in several pieces that is not apparent to a beginner since there is conflicting examples everywhere and i'm even finding some commands that don't work (verified by other posts) but are still documented...so please someone clarify this simple question for me so things become less muddy.

How do I access the related table in my view? I get error "Trying to get property of non-object (View: "  When I run this in my view

```
@foreach $programs as $program
     {{{$program->program_segment->name}}}
@endforeach
```

program is the model which works to show non-related data. program_segment is the function defined in my program model that has a has_One relation to the related table that I want to access.

Related files:

```
Model:  
class ProgramEvent extends Eloquent {

        protected $table = 'program_events';
        public $timestamps = true;

        public function program_segment()
        {
            return $this->hasOne('ProgramSegment');
        }
}
class ProgramSegment extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'program_segments';
    public $timestamps = true;

}


Migrations:

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

class CreateProgramEventsTable extends Migration {

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('program_events', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('name', 32);
            $table->date('date');
            $table->time('start_time');
            $table->time('end_time');
            $table->string('location', 32);
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('program_events');
    }
}

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

class CreateProgramSegmentsTable extends Migration {

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('program_segments', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('name', 32);
            $table->text('description');
            $table->decimal('cost', 3,2);
            $table->integer('program_event_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('program_event_id')->references('id')->on('program_events')->onDelete('cascade');

        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('program_segments');
    }
}

Controller:
    public function index()
    {
        $programs = ProgramEvent::with('program_segment')->get();
        return View::make('programs.index', compact('programs'));

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of the problem here is the lack of foreign key. You *always* need a foreign key in a relation, otherwise your database has no way to connect one record to another. The ORM has no way of knowing what data is related without a foreign key.

If your foreign key is named to follow the convention `model_id` where `model` is the name of the model in which you define the relationship, then you do not need to *specify* the name of the foreign key in the `hasOne` statement...but the foreign key still has to *exist* in the database. So if your foreign key is named `program_event_id`, your `hasOne` statement will work as-is. (In your second error message, you can see that it is expecting the column `program_event_id`.) If, however, you name your foreign key something else, you would add it to the `hasOne` definition, i.e. `return $this->hasOne('ProgramSegment', 'my_foreign_key`);'

Adding your foreign key in your migration requires two statements (in this order):

```
$table->integer('program_event_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('program_event_id')->references('id')->on('progam_events');
```

(Adding `->index()` at the end of the first line is not necessary, but the `unsigned()` is.)

---

Beyond this, some of your errors might be caused by typos in your names. Your original 'non-object' error might be caused because you controller is passing `'programs'` to your view, but in your view, you reference `$program->program_segment->name`. As far as your view is concerned, `$programs` exists, but `$program` does not.

Your foreign key constraint error might also be caused by a typo, since you define your table as `progam_events`; if this is intentional, then your foreign key definition in your migration must also reference `progam_events` and not `program_events`.

---

Once you get the foreign key set up correctly, using the `with` operator isn't *necessary* in order to access your relation—you can get the related model the way you originally did, with `$program->program_segment->name`. BUT, it is good practice, if you plan on looping over the result set of `$program` and displaying each related `program_segment->name`. Using `::with` will bring along all the related records using just 2 queries, so you don't need 1 query for each related record. This avoids something called the "N+1" problem, and makes your query more efficient.

---

Finally, all this might be unnecessary anyway...if your relationship *truly* is a one-to-one relation (so that only one event has only one segment), you can, under most circumstances, simply combine the two tables and eliminate the `hasOne` relation altogether. There are some instances where it makes sense to segment one-to-one data into two tables, but those have more to do with performance than data structure. I suspect, though, that the relationship between your two tables should be a one-to-many relation.

---

Once you get your relationships set up correctly, make sure you add a check to your `foreach` loop to make sure that a `program_segment` exists for a given `program_event` before you try to access it; otherwise, if you hit a program that doesn't have a related program_segment, you'll end up with a "Trying to get property of non-object" error:

```
@foreach $programs as $program
    @if(!is_null($program->program_segment)) 
        {{{$program->program_segment->name}}}
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: I wish the documentation I have been reading explained as well as you have. You have cleared up much for me thanks. I have edited the code with your suggestions and some updates. I also needed to add nullable to the FK to get it to migrate. I also needed to seed the table with the foreign keys (seed file not shown but I see it worked in phpmysql) You will also see the reason I used program instead of programs. I believe this is related to the error I am seeing now because I can print_r($program->program_segment) but $program->segment->name gives me the same error.

Comment: Great. If you are still getting a "trying to get property of non-object" error during your loop, you're probably hitting a record that doesn't have an associated `program_segment`...so `$program->program_segment->name` doesn't exist for that record. In your `foreach` loop, you need to add a check for the existence of a related `program_segment` before trying to access its `name` property. You can check `if(!is_null($program->program_segment))`, or simply `if($program->program_segment)`.

Comment: (Edited answer to include the check for existence of related record in your `foreach` loop.)

Comment: You are a genius and absolutely correct! I accidentally seeded more records into $program but not program_segment when I ran db:seed to seed the foreign keys in program_segment and this resulted in exactly what you described. I have added your fix and also edited my seed files to make sure they all use `DB:table('<tablename>')->delete();` at the start so it doesn't happen next time I need to refresh and reseed my database.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you need to load the relations when quering the model. You can load them using "with" operator:

Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $programs = ProgramEvent::with('program_segment')->get();
    return View::make('programs.index', compact('programs'));
}
```

**UPD:**
Also, it's always a good idea to specify directly the columns that are used in relating the tables. Here what the docs state:

```
return $this->hasOne('Model', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```

Also, I think you are missing a column in program_segmet for holding the parent id (program_event_id). Add it's good to make a foreign key, but not necessary.

Comment: I get error: 
`BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::all()`

I also was trying
`return View::make('programs.index')
        ->with('programs', ProgramEvent::all()->with('program_segment');`

but also got an error.

Comment: could it be related to having no foreign key in the related table? I see some examples put a foreign key while others say it is not needed because the ORM handles it.

Comment: Oh, big sorry man, forgot that you should use "get" in this case. Updated the answer

Comment: I changed the all() to first() and get() and I now get this error  

`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'program_segments.program_event_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from 'program_segments' where 'program_segments'.'program_event_id' in (1))`

seems that ORM is looking for the default fk but it is not in my table?

Comment: I added '$table->integer('program_event_id')->unsigned()->index();'
and migrated it into the database. I verified it added buy viewing it on phpmyadmin...but I get the initial 'non-object' error. I am trying to add the foreign key now to see it that fixes it but will need some time because there is a foreign key constraint error when I try to migrate. Will continue to work on it and let you know if that solves the issue.